# Mashable velocity graph (image)

Tags: javascript, php, graph, velocity

I was wondering how can i create Mashable like velocity graph.

I don't want it to be real actually, I just want to show **random** positive velocity graph.

How can i create such velocity graph image using PHP or JavaScript ?

I want it to look something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy7oN.png

Answer (score 1):

This is achievable using canvas & javascript.

I won't waste time listing relative resources here, simply google "Draw Canvas Graph" or similar.

You will need to store share data, which can be retrieved via social site API's. Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest, Linked In are all easy GET calls, and again a quick google will give you tutorials for that.

In principle though, you have to:

1. Record share counts over time (PHP + MySQL)
2. Load a page including this data
3. Write Javascript to draw a graph based on this data